# Telnet command does not work on windows server 2008 when connecting by putty

Tags: putty

When I connect from my PC to the windows server 2008 just using the PC console with the telnet command, and once I am on the server I do another telnet command to another device it works fine.

But when I use putty from my PC to telnet to the windows server 2008, and once I am on the server I try to do a telnet command to another device it does not work, it does not recognize the telnet command.

Anyone has a clue why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Al.

Answer (score 2):

The telent client is [not installed](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx) by default.  So the most likely answer is that it is not installed.

Telnet is a horribly insecure protocol, you should not be using it in any production capacity.  If you need to remotely use a Windows machine use WinRM via Powershell.

Comment: Hello. Telnet is enabled, we checked that. Thanks.

Comment: Well, then check your paths.  Try using a fully qualified path when running telnet.

Comment: The issue is that telnet works when we connect to the server from a pc command prompt.

Comment: It does not work when we use putty from a pc to connect to the server. I mean, we connect to the server, but the telnet command does not work.

Comment: Update your question and add some screenshots or something.  It simply isn't clear to me what your problem is.

Comment: ok, first scenario: from my pc I open the cmd and type telnet 10.10.10.1 (windows server). It works, and then I type telnet 10.10.10.2 (other device) and it works.

Comment: second scenario: From my pc I open putty and start a telnet connection to 10.10.10.1 (windows server). It works, and then I type telnet 10.10.10.2 (other device) and it does not recognize the command, so it does not work.